# Get "Text-Only" Text With PHP Strip Tags

Tags: php, html, dom, strip-tags

**I'm using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. So You Can Use It In Solutions**

Okay. So, I'm loading a file like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://localhost/seo/testfile.php');
```

And I echo the code as `echo strip_tags($html);`

So far, so good.

The problem occours when user enter inline code like

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

So I want not to display anything present inside `<script>, <style>,` etc. tags. How do I do that?

Cheers!

Comment: i think php dom will help you in way..

Answer (score 0):

i think php dom will help you and you can get required html of any element and indirectly of whole page. same like below.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$data = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach($data as $value){
    if($value->getAttribute('class')== 'notesRow'){             
        $aa = $value->nodeValue;
    }
}
```